# Produce Consumer

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I tried to implement **Producer Consumer** pattern with `wait()` and `notifyAll()` methods, but have some issues. So my code is next.

**Main class**:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List testQueue = new LinkedList();

        final Producer producer = new Producer(testQueue);
        final Consumer consumer = new Consumer(testQueue);

        Runnable prodThread = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                producer.putMessages();
            }
        };
        Runnable consThread = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                consumer.readMessages();
            }
        };

        (new Thread(prodThread)).start();
        (new Thread(consThread)).start();
    }
}
```

**Produce class**:

```
class Producer {
    private final List queue;

    public Producer(List queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void putMessages() {
        // Add batch of messages to queue
        for (int t = 1; t <= 2; t++) {
            synchronized (queue) {
                try {
                    // if size of queue is more then 2, then wait
                    while (queue.size() > 1) {
                        System.out.println("Producer: Queue is full! Size of queue is " + queue.size() +", so Producer is waiting...");
                        queue.wait();
                        // Consumer could start own work here
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
                        queue.add("String" + (i+1)*t);
                        System.out.println("Producer: Message -" + queue.get(i) + "- was added to queue...");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Producer added batch of messages, let's notify our Consumer...");
                    queue.notifyAll(); // consumer thread should be in wait set
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer class**:

```
class Consumer {
    private final List queue;

    public Consumer(List queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void readMessages() {
        synchronized (queue) {
            try {
                //while queue is empty let's wait - producer will get processor time in this case
                while (queue.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Consumer: Queue is empty! Nothing to read, so Consumer is waiting...");
                    queue.wait();
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < queue.size(); k++) {
                    System.out.println("Consumer: Read messages from queue -" + queue.get(k) + " -");
                }
                //clean our queue
                queue.removeAll(queue);
                if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Consumer finished reading, notify Producer that queue is empty, please start adding new messages for me!");
                    queue.notifyAll();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result of program execution:

```
Consumer: Queue is empty! Nothing to read, so Consumer is waiting...
Producer: Message -String1- was added to queue...
Producer: Message -String2- was added to queue...
Producer added batch of messages, let's notify our Consumer...
Consumer: Read messages from queue -String1 -
Consumer: Read messages from queue -String2 -
Consumer finished reading, notify Producer that queue is empty, please start adding new messages for me!
Producer: Message -String2- was added to queue...
Producer: Message -String4- was added to queue...
Producer added batch of messages, let's notify our Consumer...
```

Based on my code I'm expecting that **Consumer** read last messages from **Producer** (`String2`, `String4`) and print the result. But it is not happen, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Because there is no loop in the consumer. The producer loops, but not the consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread on which you run your consumer goes into `readMessages()` as intended.  There is no loop mechanism here so after it consumes the first two messages it continues execution and exits the method.

Your producer is notifying all interested threads that there are messages in the queue but the consumer is not listening.  The thread that the consumer existed on has terminated.